# How do I logout when using Spring WebFlux and OAuth 2.0 Login?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have the following `LogoutResource` that works well with Spring Boot 2.2 using Spring MVC:

```java
@RestController
public class LogoutResource {
    private ClientRegistration registration;

    public LogoutResource(ClientRegistrationRepository registrations) {
        this.registration = registrations.findByRegistrationId("oidc");
    }

    /**
     * {@code POST  /api/logout} : logout the current user.
     *
     * @param request the {@link HttpServletRequest}.
     * @param idToken the ID token.
     * @return the {@link ResponseEntity} with status {@code 200 (OK)} and a body with a global logout URL and ID token.
     */
    @PostMapping("/api/logout")
    public ResponseEntity<?> logout(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    @AuthenticationPrincipal(expression = "idToken") OidcIdToken idToken) {
        String logoutUrl = this.registration.getProviderDetails()
            .getConfigurationMetadata().get("end_session_endpoint").toString();

        Map<String, String> logoutDetails = new HashMap<>();
        logoutDetails.put("logoutUrl", logoutUrl);
        logoutDetails.put("idToken", idToken.getTokenValue());
        request.getSession().invalidate();
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(logoutDetails);
    }
}
```

The Angular client takes this response and redirects to Keycloak to log the user out. This all works great.

```js
logout(): void {
  this.authServerProvider.logout().subscribe((logout: Logout) => {
    let logoutUrl = logout.logoutUrl;
    const redirectUri = `${location.origin}${this.location.prepareExternalUrl('/')}`;

    // if Keycloak, uri has protocol/openid-connect/token
    if (logoutUrl.includes('/protocol')) {
      logoutUrl = logoutUrl + '?redirect_uri=' + redirectUri;
    } else {
      // Okta
      logoutUrl = logoutUrl + '?id_token_hint=' + logout.idToken + '&post_logout_redirect_uri=' + redirectUri;
    }
    window.location.href = logoutUrl;
  });
}
```

Now I'm trying to change it so it works with Spring WebFlux. The following seems to work and returns the expected response (I've verified this by printing the values in my Angular `logout()` method).

```java
@RestController
public class LogoutResource {
    private Mono<ClientRegistration> registration;

    public LogoutResource(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository registrations) {
        this.registration = registrations.findByRegistrationId("oidc");
    }

    /**
     * {@code POST  /api/logout} : logout the current user.
     *
     * @param idToken the ID token.
     * @return the {@link ResponseEntity} with status {@code 200 (OK)} and a body with a global logout URL and ID token.
     */
    @PostMapping("/api/logout")
    public Mono<Map<String, String>> logout(@AuthenticationPrincipal(expression = "idToken") OidcIdToken idToken) {
        return this.registration.map(oidc ->
            oidc.getProviderDetails().getConfigurationMetadata().get("end_session_endpoint").toString())
            .map(logoutUrl -> {
                Map<String, String> logoutDetails = new HashMap<>();
                logoutDetails.put("logoutUrl", logoutUrl);
                logoutDetails.put("idToken", idToken.getTokenValue());
                SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
                return logoutDetails;
            });
    }
}
```

You might notice I tried using `SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()` instead of `request.getSession().invalidate()`. This doesn't seem to work because the user is still logged in. Any idea what I need to do to kill the user's security session with WebFlux?

Comment: Are you aware of `OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler`? Take a look at the docs for usage `https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2login-advanced-oidc-logout`

Comment: I was not aware of this! Is it a recent addition to Spring Security? If I want to redirect back to the root of the current server, is that possible? IMO, that should be the default behavior and you'd only need to set it if you want to redirect somewhere else.

Comment: In other words, I'd rather not hard-code http://localhost:8080 because this would obviously need to change for staging and production.

Comment: It is new in 5.2. If you don't configure the `postLogoutRedirectUri` property than it doesn't look like it redirects back to root in application. If you would like this to be the default then please log an issue for enhancement and we'll take a look.

Comment: Done. Thanks Joe! https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/7842

Comment: No worries buddy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix this by injecting a `WebSession` and calling `invalidate()` on it.

```java
@PostMapping("/api/logout")
public Mono<Map<String, String>> logout(@AuthenticationPrincipal(expression = "idToken") OidcIdToken idToken, WebSession session) {
    return session.invalidate().then(
        this.registration.map(oidc -> oidc.getProviderDetails().getConfigurationMetadata().get("end_session_endpoint").toString())
            .map(logoutUrl -> {
                Map<String, String> logoutDetails = new HashMap<>();
                logoutDetails.put("logoutUrl", logoutUrl);
                logoutDetails.put("idToken", idToken.getTokenValue());
                return logoutDetails;
            })
    );
}
```